# Data compression techniques for receiving huge data from a Webserver onto Android

Tags: android, webserver

We are developing an App which has huge data flow to and from a Web server. We are using Rest calls to achieve the same. As the data is huge, we are currently facing some time out issues, please let us know how to increase the efficiency in receiving the data from the server, we want to know if there are any Data compression techniques that are being used. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have your own Web Service or use third party WebAPi to get data..?

Comment: Look at the answer to my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335687/java-io-ioexception-premature-eof-in-rest-in-java-using-jersey